# How to append command output to multiple files?

Tags: command-line

How can I append a command's output to multiple files?

For example, the command `man ls`, I need to append its output into three different text files using one command in terminal.

Comment: What you want to do three different files containing the output of `man ls`? I'm almost sure that nobody will delete that manual page...

Comment: @RaduRădeanu it is just an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `tee` command .

Command :

```
man ls | tee -a file1 file2 file3
```

Result : `man ls` command's output will be appended into `file1 file2 file3`

For more info : `man tee`

Reference : [Site](http://linux.101hacks.com/unix/tee-command-examples/)

Comment: If you're using zsh you can do this: `echo "Hello World" > {file1,file2,file3}` but using tee always works too

Comment: @jobin no i correct my answer , Avinash was right

Comment: good that you corrected, +1!

Comment: @nux i revert back my downvotes.